# C# Make a grocery list with a Switch Statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

whenever i run the program and select 7 it asks how many would you like which is really confusing, also I'm not sure if I'm adding the total items correctly. any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace GoingShopping
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int cabbageamount;
        private static int tomatoamount;
        private static int cheeseamount;
        private static int breadamount;
        private static int milkamount;
        private static int onionamount;
        bool isvalid = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String cabbage = "1";
            String tomatos = "2";
            String Cheese = "3";
            String bread = "4";
            String milk = "5";
            String onion = "6";
            String done = "7";
            String menu = "1) Cabbage" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "2) Tomatos" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "3) Cheese" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "4) Bread" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "5) Milk" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "6) Onion" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "7) I'm done shopping";

            int total = cabbageamount + tomatoamount + cheeseamount + breadamount + milkamount + onionamount;

            Console.Write("What you like to purchase ? " + System.Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(menu);
            string wishlist = Console.ReadLine();


            while (wishlist != "7")
            {
                switch (wishlist)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string cabbageinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        //int cabbageinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string tomatoinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string cheeseinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "4":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string breadinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "5":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string milkinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "6":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string onioninput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "7":
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to buy : " + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        Console.WriteLine(cabbageamount + "X" + "Cabbages" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          tomatoamount + "X" + "Tomatos" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          cheeseamount + "X" + "Cheese" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          breadamount + "X" + "Bread" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          milkamount + "X" + "Milk" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          onionamount + "X" + "Onions" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        Console.WriteLine("Giving a total of" + total + "items");
                        break;
                    default:    
                        break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Try : string wishlist = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

Comment: first of all your `case "7":` will never bit hit because of `while(wishlist != "7")`

Comment: @m.rogalski I think that's intended, so if you hit 7 first time round it skips it.

Comment: @m.rogalski Scratch that, you're right. Even if the wishlist is set, it will drop out of the while!

Answer (score 0):

You never set wishlist again, your last "Console.ReadLine()" throws away the result, so wishlist is always the same value.

However, as @Steve points out, you'd be better off taking a different approach completely.

As a general hint, you should use the debugger to "watch" what the values are as the program executes - then you'd notice that wishlist is the same value.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel above said you need to set the wishlist variable again

so instead of

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

put

```
wishlist = Console.ReadLine();
```

at the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `wishlist` to the value you have read. Also, you need to do that before your `switch`:

```
namespace GoingShopping
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int cabbageamount;
        private static int tomatoamount;
        private static int cheeseamount;
        private static int breadamount;
        private static int milkamount;
        private static int onionamount;
        bool isvalid = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String cabbage = "1";
            String tomatos = "2";
            String Cheese = "3";
            String bread = "4";
            String milk = "5";
            String onion = "6";
            String done = "7";
            String menu = "1) Cabbage" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "2) Tomatos" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "3) Cheese" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "4) Bread" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "5) Milk" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "6) Onion" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                          "7) I'm done shopping";

            int total = cabbageamount + tomatoamount + cheeseamount + breadamount + milkamount + onionamount;

            Console.Write("What you like to purchase ? " + System.Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(menu);
            string wishlist = "0";


            while (wishlist != "7")
            {
                wishlist = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                switch (wishlist)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string cabbageinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        //int cabbageinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string tomatoinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string cheeseinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "4":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string breadinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "5":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string milkinput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "6":
                        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
                        string onioninput = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(menu);

                        break;
                    case "7":
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to buy : " + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        Console.WriteLine(cabbageamount + "X" + "Cabbages" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          tomatoamount + "X" + "Tomatos" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          cheeseamount + "X" + "Cheese" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          breadamount + "X" + "Bread" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          milkamount + "X" + "Milk" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                                          onionamount + "X" + "Onions" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        Console.WriteLine("Giving a total of" + total + "items");
                        break;
                    default:    
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole logic for the switch statement is wrong. You should not use `string` inside your switch statements. I would suggest you to change these into `char` :

```
char charcabbage = '1'; // or 0x31
char tomatos     = '2'; // or 0x32
char Cheese      = '3'; // or 0x33
char bread       = '4'; // or 0x34
char milk        = '5'; // or 0x35
char onion       = '6'; // or 0x36
char done        = '7'; // or 0x37
```

Then you should make some `InputHandler` to handle user input and then return your "action" :

```
char ChooseAction(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    string input = string.Empty;
    while ( (input = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit") 
    {
        char c = input.Trim()[0];
        if ( c >= 0x31 && c <= 0x37)
            return c;

        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. Try again...");
    } 
    return 0x38;       
}
```

Now this method awaits for "exit" if you would like to close it or something or for valid input "1"-"7".

And as you can see now user can input values from `0x31` to `0x37` and in your `switch` statement you're running the same code 6 times so ... optimize this in a bit and change

```
//private static int cabbageamount;
//private static int tomatoamount;
//private static int cheeseamount;
//private static int breadamount;
//private static int milkamount;
//private static int onionamount;

// to this :
private static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, int> _items;
```

And initialize this before your loop begins :

```
_items = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, int>();
for(char i = '0'; i < '7'; i++) {
    _items.Add(i, 0);
}
```

Proceeding to your "pre-loop" statements now you can do somehing like :

```
char action = ChooseAction("What you like to purchase ? " + System.Environment.NewLine + menu);
```

And then proceed with your while loop :

```
while (action >= 0x31 && action <= 0x37)
```

Then just insert your `switch` statement in this format :

```
case '7':
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to buy : " + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(_items[0x31] + "X" + "Cabbages" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                          _items[0x32] + "X" + "Tomatos" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                          _items[0x33] + "X" + "Cheese" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                          _items[0x34] + "X" + "Bread" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                          _items[0x35] + "X" + "Milk" + System.Environment.NewLine,
                          _items[0x36] + "X" + "Onions" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    Console.WriteLine("Giving a total of" + total + "items");
        // set list to completed:
        action = 0x38;
    }
    break;

default :
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many would you like ? ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int temp = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(input, out temp)) {
            _items[action] += temp;
        }
        action = ChooseAction(menu);
    }
```

Now all your problems should be gone :)